# Can't define key bindings with define-key in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to bind a few keys for my `M-x ansi-term` windows in Emacs **24.1**. I tried adding the following to my `.emacs` file:

```
(define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'windomove-left)
```

But Emacs complains with:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable term-raw-map)
  (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") (quote windmove-left))
```

**Update**: Using the construction provided by dkim I can also switch to **term-char-mode**. Everything works now:

```
(add-hook 'term-load-hook
  (lambda () 
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)  ; Move to the left window
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-L") 'windmove-right) ; " " right "
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-I") 'windmove-up)    ; " " above "
    (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-K") 'windmove-down)    ; " " above "
    `term-char-mode
    ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
(add-hook 'term-load-hook
  (lambda () (define-key term-raw-map (kbd "M-J") 'windmove-left)))
```

From the `term-load-hook` variable's documentation,

> **`term-load-hook`**
>
> This hook is run when term is loaded in.
>   This is a good place to put keybindings.

Comment: Thanks, What does `lambda()` do? And where can I find the documentation on `term-load-hook`?

Comment: Also, if I want to add more key bindings, can I just place them within the same hook? Should I separate them by `;` semicolons?

Comment: @roseck `lambda` allows us to make an anonymous function: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/emacs-lisp-intro/html_node/lambda.html

Comment: @roseck You can find the documentation of `term-load-hook` by `C-h v term-load-hook` after executing `M-x ansi-term`.

Comment: Thanks! I am trying to use this hook to also automatically switch to `char-line-mode` but still get `symbol's function definition void` errors. See my update on the OP.

Comment: @roseck What is `char-line-mode`? I cannot find any information about it on the Internet.

Comment: I think you are right. The mode I am trying to switch to has a different name. In an `ansi-term` window there are two modes that you can switch into with `C-c C-j` (called `Term: line run`) and with `C-c C-k` (called `Term: char run`). I was hoping to switch into the second automatically when the `ansi-term` window becomes active.

Comment: @roseck Did you mean `term-line-mode` or `term-char-mode`? http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Term-Mode.html

Comment: You are right, I meant `term-char-mode`, but somehow the hook is still not going through.

Comment: I think I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: @roseck. I'm confused about what you really want. `term-char-mode` is enabled by default when you execute `M-x ansi-term`. Actually, the `term-char-mode` line in your post just changes the return value of the `lambda` function, so it does not have any practical meaning here. You can just remove the `term-char-mode` line if the current version really does what you want to.

Comment: OK, you are right. What I want is Emacs to **always** switch to `term-char-mode` whenever a windows running `ansi-term` becomes active. Emacs goes into `term-char-mode` automatically when I **start** an `ansi-term`, but if I switch to `term-line-mode`, then go to another window, and then go back to my terminal, Emacs will stay in `term-line-mode`. I want Emacs to always switch to `char-line-mode` whenever I make an `ansi-term` window active. How can I do that with the construction you provided?

Comment: @roseck It is a totally different question from the original one. You had better make a new post about it. I'm not sure if Emacs has a built-in mechanism for that purpose.